# What are the ways to Call an Input box to fill data in it using selenium , if call by i.d fails to identify the box?

Tags: python, selenium

`

```
for data in form_data:
    driver.find_element_by_id('name').send_keys(data['name'])
    driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(data['email'])
    driver.find_element_by_id('message').send_keys(data['message'])
    driver.find_element_by_id('submit').click()
```

`
In the above code, It is unable to get the input box from the given Id, Although Id is mentioned while inspecting the input Box.

I read about xpath but unable to use it to get the input box.I want to select the input box and send data to fill the form and submit it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what is the website containing the input box?